# Excel to Access strings as numbers

Tags: excel, ms-access

Not sure if this can be done through Access or some simple code in Excel?  But say I have in Excel a few rows like so:

```
CARD             TRIGGER          CATEGORY     QUANTITY TARGET
Magma Drake      StartOfTurn    Damage            1     Opponent
Lava Moat        ReciveDamage   Damage            5     AttackingCards
Rockslide        AfterCasting   Damage            15    AllOpponentCards
Ash Imp          AfterCasting   Damage            5     TargetOpponentCard
Eruption         AfterCasting   Damage            15    TargetOpponentCard
Eruption         AfterCasting   Damage            15    Opponent
Lava Streams     StartOfTurn    Mana               2    OwnerMana
Firebomb Troll   Death          Damage             8    AllOpponentCards
Scorched Avata   AfterCasting   Damage             8    Opponent
Scorched Avata   AfterCasting   Damage             8    Owner
Hero of Flame    AfterCasting   Stats              3    AllOwnersCards
Falling Stars    AfterCasting   DamagePlus         8    Opponent
Falling Stars    AfterCasting   DamagePlusPercent  4    AllOpponentCards
```

I want to be able to export this to Access, but instead of strings for the TRIGGER, CATEGORY and TARGET, I want to use numbers. Thus:

```
StartOfTurn = 1
ReciveDamage = 2
AfterCasting = 3
Death = 4
```

ect... for all 3 columns.  I was not sure if I could put in an alias value for strings and then export the alias value?  How can I do this? Also note I would like to keep the string values in Excel as its easier for me to understand, but its easier for code if the values in Access are numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i used the best approach, but i created a lookup table like Brian said, but in excel. So i had something like

```
B1                B2
triggers       triggers_numbers
startofturn       1
endofturn         5
endofturn         5
Afterattack       4
startofturn       1
```

Then when i imported the data to access, i used the values in trigger_numbers instead of triggers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be:

1. Create "lookup" tables (say, named Triggers, Cateogories, and Targets) in Access that list the numbers that correspond to the strings.
2. Import or link your existing Excel data into a "staging" table in Access.
3. Write a query in Access that joins the staging table to the lookup tables to "look up" the numbers based on the strings.
4. Use the query directly, or run a make table query or an append query based on it to transfer the results to a separate table and use that table instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to export the whole table into Access and then run an Update query in Access to replace the values you want replaced.  So far as I know, you can't update values only on export, you would have to first replace them in Excel which you said you don't want to do.

Also, for the record, it would be very easy to keep this all in Access if you used dropdowns (aka Combo boxes) to choose your values.  You could display the full string, but only store the number in the table.